# Explain Python subsetting

Tags: python, pandas, subset, slice

I'm having trouble understanding the output of **y[train]** below:

```
y = df1['casual'].values
out: array([ 3,  8,  5, ...,  7, 13, 12], dtype=int64)

train = np.random.choice([True, False], num_row, replace = True, p = [0.5, 0.5])
out: array([False,  True, False, ..., False,  True,  True])

y[train]
out: array([ 8,  0,  8, ...,  8, 13, 12], dtype=int64)
```

I'm assuming that the 'True','False' in train variable evaluates to 1, 0. So am I right to think of y[train] as [3, 8, 5,...][0, 1, 0...]. Could someone pls explain how y[train] is derived?

Comment: `DataFrame` is not normal list and `y[train]` doesn't work like index in normal list. It doesn't evaluate to `1`, `0` . It uses `True` to keep row and `False` to skip row.

Comment: You can also check [`Boolean array indexing`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) for numpy and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)  for pandas.